# Export menu configuration

Tags: 8, navigation, configuration

Looking for a way to export menu configuration. The Configuration management system will export the menu itself, but not the menu links configuration. I am looking for a way to put one of those mega menus into version control to import/export through multiple environments.

If anyone has found a good way to do this. I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: The latest option is https://www.drupal.org/project/structure_sync
I think it is the best option, it also support other things like taxonomies

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Menu links can come from 3 sources:

- Views module (these can be exported when the view config is exported)
- `.links.yml` file in a module (not possible to export)
- Created menu links (Is content entities, like nodes, users, etc and is not possible to export)

I'm guessing you are creating menu links via interface, which is content. The config system can't export content, which is by design. If you wanted to synchronize content, you would need to look at the [Deploy](https://www.drupal.org/project/deploy) module suite. I'm not sure how well this is working atm, since it's still in alpha.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand the reasoning, that menu links can reference paths which Drupal assumes are nodes and that nodes are not config and are therefore non exportable via config-export. I wish it were otherwise and haven't ceased to search for ways to do this.

Answer (score 3):

My experience with Drupal 8 step by step

First of all, you need to install [Menu Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_export) module and activate it. After that, you will have Export Menu in the Structure part.

> **Steps to Export & Import**

1- In the Export Menu page `domain.com/admin/config/development/menu_export`, you have three option, at **Menu list** select which menus you want to export.

2- On the Export section, export your menus.

**(In this step menu setting will not be exported on YML file then you need to continue.)**

3- Now you need to export system configuration from `domain.com/admin/config/development/configuration/full/export` or `drush cex`

**Note: after export, you will have `menu_export.export_data.yml` file that contains your menu settings**

4- Transfer configuration anywhere you want, then you need to import them from `domain.com/admin/config/development/configuration/full/import` or `drush cim`

5- Then you need to import menus to your system from UI `domain.com/admin/config/development/menu_export/import`

> **Important Note**
>
> Clear your cache
>
> In some cases, mostly with **Administration** menu you need do and **extra step**. That you need to just open the edit Administration menu page and just saving it without any changes after this you should see your updated menu on administration as well.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [Config Menu Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_link_config) module.

Comment: Tested it on a D8.6 and would not recommend it. Would not see this as a stable solution. Had to uninstall after some nasty errors.

Answer (score 2):

There's also [Menu Import and Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_export):

> This module helps in exporting and importing Menu Items among cloned
>   sites which is not possible using CMI.
>
> This module exports the menu entity as config YAML and will be
>   imported on subsequent instances.