# Drush config-import/export

Tags: 8, drush, configuration

I'am trying to export menu items but the generated yaml files does not contains any reference to this elements. All menu files look like this:

```
uuid: 12....04
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: how-works
label: 'How it works'
description: 'Menu description'
locked: false
```

Is there a way to export/import menu elements?

Answer (score 0):

Menu items, content nodes, taxonomy terms, etc. are not handled through the Configuration API. Configuration API is meant to handle... well, configuration.

A fast Google search returned [Config menu link](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_link_config).
I have not tested that module, but if it works, it should do what you need there.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found [this other question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/196456/export-d8-menu-configuration) that also explains that menus are not exportable. It also says that I may write menus in `.links.yml` that makes it versionable from git. It is not really import/export, but it works for me.